# Angular 15 - Childcomponent is not updating UI when input has changed

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I've got a component containing 2 childcomponents:

```
<span>Timings:</span>
<sir-project-fasetiming [faseTiming]="projectTiming.timingInitiatie" (faseTimingChanged)="faseTimingChanged($event, 'timingInitiatie')"></sir-project-fasetiming>
<sir-project-fasetiming [faseTiming]="projectTiming.timingOnderzoek" (faseTimingChanged)="faseTimingChanged($event, 'timingOnderzoek')"></sir-project-fasetiming>
```

The projectTiming is fetched in the onInit:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    const self = this;
    this.timingService.resolveTimings().then((projectTiming) => {
        self.projectTiming = projectTiming;
    });
```

Now when i change some input inside the sir-project-fasetiming (timingInitiatie) the (faseTimingChanged)="faseTimingChanged($event, 'timingInitiatie') is triggered.

This method changes the projectTiming.timingOnderzoek. But the UI is not picking up the changes.

```
    public faseTimingChanged(timing: ProjectFaseTiming, prop: string): void {
      this.projectTiming['timingOnderzoek'].gepland.from = this.tarmaDateService.addDays(this.projectTiming[prop].gepland.to, 1);
    }
```

Any reason why the sir-project-fasetiming [faseTiming]="projectTiming.timingOnderzoek" isnt showing the newly assigned this.projectTiming['timingOnderzoek'].gepland.from ?

Comment: You might have to implement OnChanges interface and implement ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned earlier in the comments, you need to implement OnChanges interface in your component.

Or without OnChanges:

```
...

private faceTiming$ = new BehaviourSubject<TypeOfYourData>(null);

@Input('faceTiming')
set _faceTiming(data: TypeOfYourData): void {
  this.faceTiming$.next(data);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.faceTiming$.subscribe(data => this.faceTiming = data);
}

...
```